# Fields that are a relationships dont be appeared by callback create in SailsJS

Tags: callback, sails.js, sails-mongo, after-create

I have the following Media schema

```
    module.exports = {
        attributes: {
            user: {
                model: 'user',
                required: true
            },
            jobs: {
                collection: 'job',
                via: 'media'
            }
        },
        afterCreate: generateJob,
    }
```

The method generateJob the media object is like that

```
{
  user: '55dcd2db428f50ea1ecf670e'
}
```

But job field doesnt appear and I need it because I want to associate one job to media but media doesnt get the media.jobs.add() method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve the data from an association, you must invoke the `.populate()` method; waterline does not automatically populate this data (it it is too expensive and too rarely necessary to be a core feature, in my humble opinion).

Somewhere along the line (e.g. in `generateJob`), you'll need to do something like this:

`Media.find(...).populate('jobs')`, at which point you'll be able to invoke `.add()` and `.remove()` on the associated collection.